# Initializing while declaring a variable vs doing it on separate lines in c

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, variable-assignment

Please note that I am doing this strange assignment not because I am unclear of the syntax or am new to c.

I was just trying out what would happen if an int was assigned an array:

```
int a = {1, 2, 3};
```

To this I got the following warning:

```
 warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  int a = {1, 2, 3};
              ^
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  int a = {1, 2, 3};
                 ^
```

and when I print the contents of a, I get `1`.

But when I do this:

```
int a;
a = {1, 2, 3};
```

I get an error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  a = {1, 2, 3};
      ^
```

Though I know arrays are not meant to be assigned to `int` variables, the above results lead me to question:

- the difference between `int x; x = ...` and `int x = ...`

and

- what exactly causes the warning or the error message?

Comment: They're both wrong and it is up to the compiler writer what the contents of the error message is , and any behaviour

Comment: So the error message or the warning is completely independent of the way in which I do the initialization (directly vs on two separate lines)?

Comment: It could be that the compiler assigns its address at initialization or it automatically dereferences to the first element, etc. etc. but not in case of assignment, it actually really depends on how the compiler is designed. Try running your code in different compilers to see the change...

Comment: Write `int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco, or even better, `int a[ ] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, I am aware I am not  doing a valid assignment. Was just curious about this behavior I noticed. Thanks @AlejandroBlasco

Comment: You defined `a` as an integer and initialized it with an array. That's bad and the compiler alerts you that he was expecting an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all,

```
int a = {1, 2, 3};
```

is a definition and **initialization** statement, and

```
int a;
a = {1, 2, 3};
```

is a definition and **assignment** statement.

They have different rules. The syntax `{1, 2, 3}` is called a brace-enclosed initializer list, that can be used in an initialization statement, not in an assignment - it's a syntax error. So, that answers about the error in the second snippet.

For the first snippet, for a scalar, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9/P11

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. [...]

So, the expression `{1, 2, 3}` attempts to provide more that one element, which is excess. That's what your compiler is warning you about.

Comment: @Inian As you should know, actual standard document is not free. There are draft versions that are available for free online. and yes, I refer to the same one you're pointing out. I'd refrain from adding links here as I cannot guarantee the availability of those (unofficial) sources. A quick google search should lead you to the draft versions.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents